# Join table A on table B and select only the first occurrence from B after specific date from table A

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to determine the best way to do the following....  Table a has a specific start_date.  table b has a bunch of dollar amounts with various dates based on payments received and when.  I only want to show the row from table b with the first date occurrence >= the start_date from table a.  I also do not want to retrieve duplicates ID numbers which is what I am encountering now.

I have something like this so far...

```
Select a.ID, a.Start_Date
From a
Left Join (Select ID, Min(Recd_Dt) as Mindate, Total_Recd
Group by ID, Total_Recd) b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Start_Date <= b.Mindate
```

table a looks like this...

```
ID | Start_Dt  
1  | 11/2/2017  
2  | 11/3/2017
```

table b looks like this...

```
ID | Recd_Dt    | Total_Recd  
1  | 11/1/2017  | $600  
1  | 11/10/2017 | $800  
1  | 11/19/2017 | $100  
2  | 11/2/2017  | $200  
2  | 11/5/2017  | $600  
2  | 11/6/2017  | $100
```

Id Like to see something like this...

```
ID | Recd_Dt    | Total_Recd  | Sum_of_Total_Recd_After_Start  
1  | 11/10/2017 | $800        | $900  
2  | 11/5/2017  | $600        | $700
```

furthermore, I'd like to also have a second join on the same table b that will give me a sum of any amount that occurred after the Start_Date

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I just edited the original post.  I'm sorry about that!

Comment: Is it possible to have additional rows in table a for the same ID? If yes, how to deal with those?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    b.Recd_Dt, 
    b.Total_Recd, 
    SUM(Total_Recd) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID) AS Sum_of_Total_Recd_After_Start 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Recd_Dt > a.Start_Dt
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.Start_Dt) = 1
```

1) Get all rows from table "a"
2) Get related rows from table "b" with Recd_Dt > Start_Dt
3) ROW_NUMBER orders rows by the earliest Start_Dt per each ID
4) QUALIFY ... = 1 keeps only the first row per ID grouping
5) SUM(Total_Recd) adds up the Total_Recd column per each ID grouping

I haven't tested it, but let me know if it works.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for however I did write in a where statement and I am receiving a syntax error when I try and join a 3rd table. The syntax error I'm receiving is "Expected something between an integer and the left keyword". Do you know how I should adjust this join to solve for this?  If it helps I'm looking to add a where statement on table b Where Total_Recd > 0. I'll need to join another table c but it's a normal left join c on a.ID = c.ID.

Comment: @nbwest76: If the above query solved your problem, its better to close this question and add a new question giving reference of the current question with newly added information you shared in comments. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you added the LEFT JOIN after the QUALIFY clause.  If so, you need to move it up in the query.  Stick it right after the first INNER JOIN.  You should order the clauses in your queries something like:  

`SELECT  ___
FROM ___
JOIN ___
WHERE ___
HAVING ___
QUALIFY ___
ORDER BY ___`